# Express(NodeJS) JQuery ajax call returns 500, the same call with Postman returns a 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Say I have the following API endpoint defined using the express framework

```
router.post('/mypost', function (req, res, next){
  console.log("Request body" + req.body);
  res.json({some: "data"});
});
```

If I use a client like Postman and send a POST request, I can see that "Request body[object Object]" is outputted to the console and a 200 OK response is returned.
However if I make a similar call using JQuery (I haven't tried a vanilla JavaScript XMLHttpRequest method) such as the following

```
$.post("/mypost", {
      request: "data"
    }, function (result) {
});
```

It gives me a 500 error on my NodeJS console output. Can anyone explain why POSTing a similar request using the Postman client succeeds but when I call the same endpoint using JQuery $.post it throws a 500 error.

Comment: We have no clue why.... what does the postman request look like? So what error is in your server log?

Comment: `500` means server error, is there nothing else logged to the Node.js console?

Comment: I would compare request Headers of Browser and Postman calls.

Comment: Let's play a little game I like to call "What's the Difference?".  Look at each of the requests (fiddler, wireshark, chrome debugger, etc.) and do a diff.

Comment: Consider adding the content type to your ajax call.

Comment: Could it be that body is not defined in the jQuery request and it's throwing an undefined error?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the response, I checked the request headers, the JQuery AJAX call was sending the data using the following content type Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 whereas Postman was sending it as application-json. Any reason why sending it like this would cause an issue?